# Display - Remove X with a toggle button?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to have button that when pressed, removes all the 'X' from several cells. And when pressed again puts them back in.

For now, I don't have the button but I can only remove the 'X' with the method .clear() but I can not put the 'X' back in as I stored all the 'X' previously in an array but if I run the script again, the array will take the empty values of my cells after the clear() method has been ran ..... any ideas ?

```
 function displayx(){

  ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  // I want to store the 'X' in the variable data but if I run this script a second time, the array data will have empty values
  var data= sheet.getRange(2,12,sheet.getLastRow()-1,43).getValues();
  var rangetoclear=sheet.getRange(2,13,sheet.getLastRow()-1,43);

  // cell reference (2,7) would have the true/ false condition for the X to be displayed...
  if (sheet.getRange(2,7).getValue()==true)
    {
       rangetoclear.clearContent();
    } else {
       rangetoclear.setValues(data);    
       Logger.log(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can store the removed X rows and columns in another sheet.  It would be easier to help you if you can share a copy of your spreadsheet.  In particular I'm wondering do the cell's that contain Xs only contain and X or do they contain other things.

Comment: Hi @Cooper thank you for this suggestion. It does help. But I would have the same problem because if I run the script again once the main sheet with the 'X's cleared out, then the second sheet would take these empty values...would you know if I can add a toggle button which would forbid me to run the same script if the data in the first sheet is an empty range ? ( I can't share the sheet unfortunately)

Comment: That all depends upon how you write the script and I would write it so that the script is the vehicle for changing the stored locations of removed Xs.   If you don't want to use a sheet to store the values you can use PropertiesService but I find it a lot easier to change the data in a sheet rather than using PropertiesService.  But it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks @Cooper, I am using a second sheet after hearing about your suggestion. I have been checking this PropertiesService but I do not really understand how it works... would you have any kind of tutorial for the use of this ?

Comment: Try Googling PropertiesService Google Apps Script.  You should find several links on this site alone.

Comment: I am not sure, if I understood your question correctly. So you have a range, where some of the cells contain an 'X'. Do you want to delete the whole content of all the cells that contain a 'X'? Or do you want to just delete the 'X' - e.g. change the cell content from 'XEROX' to 'ERO'?